# How to merge with wildcard? - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, wildcard

I have two dataframes which I want to merge. The join column of the right dataframe is possibly containing *wildcard* values (say: "ALL") which should match *every* value in the join column of the left dataframe.

Think of the following minimal example:

```
entities = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict([
    { 'name' : 'Boson', 'type' : 'Material' },
    { 'name' : 'Atman', 'type' : 'Ideal' },
])

recommendations = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict([
    { 'action' : 'recognize', 'entity_type' : 'ALL'},
    { 'action' : 'disdain', 'entity_type' : 'Material'},
    { 'action' : 'worship', 'entity_type' : 'Ideal'},
])
```

`recommendations` can be interpreted as a set of recommendations as of
"Recognize *all Entities, regardless of their type*, disdain Entities which are Material, and worship Entities which are Ideal"). I now want to have a dataFrame which contains all entitities, together with their recommended actions. So, in this example the resulting dataframe should look

```
    name recommendation      type
0  Boson      recognize  Material
1  Boson        disdain  Material
2  Atman      recognize     Ideal
3  Atman        worship     Ideal
```

**Is there a pandaic way to do this?**

I know how I can get there by creating a dataframe which contains the Cartesian Product of `entities` and `recommendations` and then cutting it down on conditions.

I can also think of a solution where I get a series of all `types` existing in `entitities` and creating a row for each type for each row in `recommendations` with a wildcard type.

But in my real problem I actually have multiple columns which I want to join on with wildcard values. So a smart and efficient pandaic way would help me a lot.

Comment: I was going to say you could split the recommendations into two frames: one that has wildcards and one which does not.  But the last part where you say you have many columns containing wildcards makes this unappealing.  I think you may do well to just iterate over the columns and build one big frame with all the wildcards expanded.  Would the resulting expanded frame be too large to be practical?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I think, what you mean by "one big frame with all the wildcards expanded" is the same as I wanted to describe with "a solution where I get a series of all types existing in entitities and creating a row for each type for each row in recommendations with a wildcard type". Yes, I can do so. But it would be better to have a function which makes use of the pandas dataFrame structure. And I feel like loosing the advantages of pandas.merge if I do it that way. But of course it's possible,

Comment: @JohnZwinck my approach gets rid of iterating what do you think about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is my replacing wildcard from all the other elements present and then merge them i.e

**Data** :

```
edf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([
    { 'name' : 'Boson', 'type' : 'Material' },
    { 'name' : 'Atman', 'type' : 'Ideal' },
])

rdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([
    { 'action' : 'recognize', 'entity_type' : 'ALL'},
    { 'action' : 'disdain', 'entity_type' : 'Material'},
    { 'action' : 'worship', 'entity_type' : 'Ideal'},
])
```

**Preprocessing** :

```
mask = rdf['entity_type']=='ALL'

# Join all the elements from `edf['type']` with `;` since you might have `,`s in types and we need to use set to get rid of duplicates (Thank you @John  )
all_ =  ';'.join(set(edf['type'])) # all_ : Material,Ideal

# Replace all by newly obatined string 
rdf['entity_type'] = np.where(mask,all_,rdf['entity_type'])

rdf
      action     entity_type
0  recognize  Material;Ideal
1    disdain        Material
2    worship           Ideal

# Split and stack so we can make `entity_type` one dimensional
rdf = rdf.set_index('action')['entity_type'].str.split(';',expand=True)\
        .stack().reset_index('action').rename(columns={0:'type'})

rdf
          action     type
 0  recognize    Material
 1  recognize       Ideal
 0    disdain    Material
 0    worship       Ideal
```

**Merge**:

```
ndf = edf.merge(rdf,on='type').rename(columns={'action':'recommendation'})

ndf

   name      type recommendation
0  Boson  Material      recognize
1  Boson  Material        disdain
2  Atman     Ideal      recognize
3  Atman     Ideal        worship
```

Sample run on different dataframes :

```
edf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([
    { 'name' : 'Boson', 'type' : 'Material' },
    { 'name' : 'Atman', 'type' : 'Ideal' },
    { 'name' : 'Chaos', 'type' : 'Void, but emphasized' },
    { 'name' : 'Tohuwabohu', 'type' : 'Void' },
]) 

rdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([
    { 'action' : 'recognize', 'entity_type' : 'ALL'},
    { 'action' : 'disdain', 'entity_type' : 'Material'},
    { 'action' : 'worship', 'entity_type' : 'Ideal'},
    { 'action' : 'drink', 'entity_type' : 'ALL'}
])
```

Then:

```
mask = rdf['entity_type']=='ALL'
all_ =  ';'.join(set(edf['type']))
rdf['entity_type'] = np.where(mask,all_,rdf['entity_type'])

rdf = rdf.set_index('action')['entity_type'].str.split(';',expand=True)\
        .stack().reset_index('action').rename(columns={0:'type'})
ndf = edf.merge(rdf,on='type').rename(columns={'action':'recommendation'})

ndf

         name                  type recommendation
0       Boson              Material      recognize
1       Boson              Material        disdain
2       Boson              Material          drink
3       Atman                 Ideal      recognize
4       Atman                 Ideal        worship
5       Atman                 Ideal          drink
6       Chaos  Void, but emphasized      recognize
7       Chaos  Void, but emphasized          drink
8  Tohuwabohu                  Void      recognize
9  Tohuwabohu                  Void          drink
```

This approach is fast and consumes less memory than a cartesian product. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I guess you should use `.unique()` when constructing `all_`, otherwise you may get duplicates.

Comment: Thank you sir for pointing it, I used `set` instead of `.unique()`.

Comment: This is close to the solution. But it fails if `rdf` does not contain all entity_types, for instance if 
`rdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([ { 'action' : 'recognize', 'entity_type' : 'ALL'}])` . So, the entity types should be taken from `edf`, not from `rdf`. I know, I maybe was not 100% clear in specifying that in my question. But with *wildcard* I mean "a value which matches every (better to say: *arbirtrary*) value in the left table join column".

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach though I came up with fix still not sure if it might fit all the cases. Do check once i.e we can use `all_ =  ','.join(set(edf['type']))` Hope that helps. Sorry for that misunderstanding.

Comment: OK, That's good so far. Obviously, this is breaking if there is an entity_type with a comma. For instance, `edf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([
    { 'name' : 'Boson', 'type' : 'Material' },
    { 'name' : 'Atman', 'type' : 'Ideal' },
    { 'name' : 'Chaos', 'type' : 'Void, but emphasized' },
    { 'name' : 'Tohuwabohu', 'type' : 'Void' },
])
` And that makes me think of this solution as a rather 'hacky' way.

Comment: As I said its really hard to comeup with a solution that fits every case for this kind of questions. You might need to open a bounty for getting the best solution. This is all I could help. I need to write my assignments. Have a good day

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach for your latest comment we can use `;` as separator tell me if you face any other problem

Comment: I am thinking of a method that would involve str.get_dummies... still testing but no guarantees. This seems the most viable solution, even if it is a bit ugly.

Comment: I too am very curious for get_dummies

Comment: @Barath: Just exchanging the character would only shift the problem. I think, it would be better to escape the separator we use in the `type` column before applying the wildcard-merge an unescaping it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about this, I think that the way of using the Cartesian Product of the two dataframes is probably not such a bad idea as I thought before. So for anyone reading this thread in the future, I just want to show how this can be done:

```
# get Cartesian Product of the two dfs
entities['join'] = recommendations['join'] = 0
results = entities.merge(recommendations, on='join')
# extract matching rows
results = results[(( results['type'] == results['entity_type']) | (results['entity_type'] == "ALL"))]
results = results[['name', 'type', 'action']]
```

With input

```
entities = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([
    { 'name' : 'Boson', 'type' : 'Material' },
    { 'name' : 'Atman', 'type' : 'Ideal' },
    { 'name' : 'Chaos', 'type' : 'Void, but emphasized' },
    { 'name' : 'Tohuwabohu', 'type' : 'Void' },
])

recommendations = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([
    { 'action' : 'recognize', 'entity_type' : 'ALL'},
    { 'action' : 'disdain', 'entity_type' : 'Material'},
    { 'action' : 'disdain', 'entity_type' : 'Void'},
    { 'action' : 'worship', 'entity_type' : 'Ideal'},
])
```

this leads to `results`:

```
          name                  type     action
0        Boson              Material  recognize
1        Boson              Material    disdain
4        Atman                 Ideal  recognize
7        Atman                 Ideal    worship
8        Chaos  Void, but emphasized  recognize
12  Tohuwabohu                  Void  recognize
14  Tohuwabohu                  Void    disdain
```

Comment: But also make sure this would be slow if you have a huge dataframe, consumes a huge memory, since you are doing cartesian product