# How can I do an aggregation with a lot of different conditions in pandas efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

### Problem

I have a dataframe `data` with a variable amount of categorial columns (CC) and one numerical column (NC) containing numbers. The combination of all CC is unique, I could also use them as an index. Now I am given a second dataframe `choices` with the same CC, but some cells are set to `np.nan` which is understood as a wildcard. I wish to aggregate the NC in `data` based on CC in `choices`.

### Example

Here is an example in case of a summation:

| data | Fruit | Color | Size | NC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Apple | Green | Small | 1 |
| 1 | Apple | Yellow | Medium | 2 |
| 2 | Banana | Yellow | Small | 3 |

| choices | Fruit | Color | Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NaN | Yellow | NaN |
| 1 | Apple | Green | Small |
| 2 | Apple | NaN | Large |
| 3 | Banana | Red | Small |

What I want to obtain is:

|  | Fruit | Color | Size | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NaN | Yellow | NaN | 5 |
| 1 | Apple | Green | Small | 1 |
| 2 | Apple | NaN | Large | 0 |
| 3 | Banana | Red | Small | 0 |

In reality there are ~10 categories and up to several thousand rows in `data` and `choices`.

### Using `DataFrame.apply`

For a single `row` in `choices` I can obtain the result doing something like (won't run, just the idea)

```
def aggregate_single_row(row, data):
    mask = (data == data)
    for c in row.columns:
        if not pd.isna(row[c]):
            mask &= (data[c] == row[c])
    return data[mask].sum()
```

and `DataFrame.apply` that function to `choices`. However, that requires Python-looping over `choices` which is rather inefficient. In fact, if `len(choices)` is considerably larger than `len(data)`, it is much faster (up to 100x) to just convert everything to Python lists and do nested `for`-loops.

### Simulating a "Wildcard Merge"

If there was a "wildcard-merge", it would be rather easy to obtain the sum using

```
CC = ['Fruit', 'Color', 'Size']
data.merge(choices, on=CC, wildcard=np.nan).groupby(CC).sum()
```

Inspired by that idea, I followed [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47473249/17482482) to skip Python loops entirly by

1. creating a unique index in `choices`,
2. replacing any `np.nan` by a list of all possible values in that particular column,
3. using `explode` successively on all columns to expand the wildcards,
4. merging `data` and `choices` on the CC
5. and grouping the merge result by the unique index of step 1.

Turns out, that this method is even slower than the `apply`-method, probably because of the huge amount of wildcards in `choices`.

### Summary

So my observation is, that the code runs faster the more Python `for`-loops I use. Since the tale is that it should be the other way around, I wonder if you can come up with a better solution, that outperforms the naive "nested `for`-loop" approach.

Comment: There is certainly better solutions than the "nested for-loop". However, having this naive algorithm and an input data code (that produces a slow computation) should help us a lot since then we could check if our solution can be better than the naive one (and actually correct too). Can you provide that? Besides this, I think there is no better algorithm than iterating over the data row (`Dat`), the choice row (`Chx`) and the columns (`Col`), so with a complexity `O(Dat * Chx * Col)`, due to the wildcard. Still, this does not mean the pure-Python solution is fastest (vectorization may help).